How to use a FromForm with Refit (dotnet)
I'm working on a web api developed in .net 7. There is an endpoint that receives a [FromForm] for an entity that contains an IFormFile, an enum, and a string.
The endpoint is working as expected, I can send files and fill all the needed information using swagger.
The issue is with the Refit client. I already tried two different approaches, but I always get a NotFound exception.
Here is an example of the code I used.
// FilesController
[HttpPost("/files", Name = nameof(UploadFile))]
public async Task<ActionResult<FileResponse>> UploadFile(
    [FromForm] UploadFileRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
 // code
}

// FileRequest
public record UploadFileRequest
{
    public required IFormFile File { get; set; }
    public required FilePurpose Type { get; set; }
    public required string Description { get; set; }
}

public enum FilePurpose{
  Input,
  Output
}

In the Refit side, here are the two attempts I tried:
// Attemp 1
[Multipart]
[Post("/files")]
Task<FileResponse> UploadFile(
    UploadFileRequestRefit request,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);

public record UploadFileRequestRefit
{
    public required MultipartItem File { get; set; }
    public required FilePurpose Type { get; set; }
    public required string Description { get; set; }
}

// Attemp 2
[Multipart]
[Post("/files")]
Task<FileResponse> UploadFile(
    [AliasAs("file")] MultipartItem file,
    [AliasAs("type")] FilePurpose type,
    [AliasAs("description")] string description,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);


your api declares it as /file when your refit says /files

sorry, this was my mistake in pasting the example. the route is ok because I have other endpoints in the same controller that are working well

You can try this approach:
[Post("/files")]
Task<FileResponse> UploadFile([Body(BodySerializationMethod.UrlEncoded)]
    UploadFileRequestRefit request,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

File param should be sent as byte array format. Aliases should be corrected as well. This worked for me.
[Multipart]
[Post("/files")]
Task<FileResponse> UploadFile(
    [AliasAs("File")] byte[] file,
    [AliasAs("Type")] FilePurpose type,
    [AliasAs("Description")] string description,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);

